# not showing qml application on display

Tags: raspberry-pi, qml, qt5, raspbian, egl

I'm trying to run a simple qml on my raspberry. Raspbian jessie (the latest), qt5, if it is connected via cdmi to a monitor, it works. If it is connected to my Waveshare 3.2 display, nothing appears on the screen (and no error). Seems like it doesn't understand that my device is /dev/fb1 now..
That's my sh:

```
export QT_SELECT=5
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_DEBUG=1
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_FB=/dev/fb1
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_WIDTH=320
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_HEIGHT=240
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH=860
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT=350
qml /home/pi/XXX/main2.qml
```

What should I do or check in this case?